# jmsTemplate is not auto initializing in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms, jmstemplate

Below is my following Spring Boot Application where I am trying to send the message to Queue but it always throw the NULL on `jmsTemplate`. Per Spring documentation `jmsTemplate` should auto configured but it is not happening. is that something I am doing wrong here?

Service class

```
@Service
@EnableJms
public class CTCall {
       @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate; //THIS ALWAYS Throw NULL


    public String send() {
        try {
            System.out.println("jmsTemplate:  " + jmsTemplate);
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("MYQUEUE", "Hello World!");
            return "OK";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "FAIL";
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=MYMGR
ibm.mq.channel=MYQUUE
ibm.mq.connName=MYHOST(1414)
ibm.mq.user=
ibm.mq.password=
```

POM

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add @EnableJms to a @SpringBootApplication or @Configuration class

Comment: simon Martinelli  so you are saying remove @EnableJms from my service class and add to my Application.java?

Comment: Yes. That's what I say

Comment: I tried but still coming NULL on jmsTemplate.

Comment: How does your package structure look like? Is CTCall bellow the application class?

Comment: This is how it is
com.jms.service.CTCall
com.jms.Application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232713/discussion-between-user1591156-and-simon-martinelli).